# Is there a vim errorformat that will catch a function name instead of a line number?

Tags: vim, errorformat

I am trying to write an `errorformat` for vim that will catch a function name and convert it to a line number so that the errors point at least to the general location of the error. Being able to still include the function name in the error message would be ideal.

Here is an example error message that I would like to catch

```
(filename.foo) WARNING! Error message about problem in function 'function()'
```

So what I would like is for it to take the `function()` part and convert it to the line number on which the function is defined, which would probably require some sort of ctags integration. Is this possible?

Comment: For what language/compiler? What use is that compiler if it can't tell you the line of an error?

Comment: It is a custom in house language that my employer uses. There are a number of less-than-ideal aspects to the language and compiler, but it is not something I can easily change at this time. The next version should be better, but for the time being I am stuck with this older version.